# api platform: delete a file after handling

Tags: api-platform.com

I followed the [documentation](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/file-upload/#handling-file-upload) to upload files to my public folder, and now I wish I could delete a file from that folder.

if I use the query provided by api platform: api/image/{id} I can only delete the row in my table. I would already have to retrieve the path of the image to save it in the table. And maybe then I can use it to delete the image?

I need a Deserializer ?

Laurent.

Answer (score -1):

You need to create an `EventListener` and listen to the `postRemove` event so that after deleting an entry from the `Image` entity, you physically remove the file from the directory.

An example of listening for events on an Image entity:

```
class ImageEventSubscriber
{
 
    public function postRemove(Image $image, LifecycleEventArgs $event){

        $image_path =  $image->getPath(); // You may have to specify the full path to the file if it is not listed in the database.

        if (file_exists($image_path))
        {
            unlink($image_path);
        }

    }
}
```

Now you need to declare your event listener in the services.yaml file

```
  App\EventListener\ImageEventSubscriber: 
    tags: [ { name: doctrine.orm.entity_listener, entity: App\Entity\Image, event: postRemove } ]
```

---

Now, when requesting `DELETE: api/image/{id}`, the record and file will be deleted. You can get more information about EventSubscriber by reading the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html).